# Alfresco: Define a custom type that contains files as properties

Tags: alfresco

I would like to create a custom model for a whitepaper that consists of the following properties:

- Published Date
- Author
- Audio File
- PDF File

How can I specify that two of the last two are **files**?

```xml
<types>
    <type name="sc:whitepaper">
        <title>Whitepaper</title>
        <parent>cm:content</parent>
        <properties>
            <property name="sc:publishedDate">
                <type>d:datetime</type>
            </property>
            <property name="sc:author">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="sc:audioFile">
                <type>d:text</type>     <!-- How do I state this property is a file? -->
            </property>
            <property name="sc:pdfFile">
                <type>d:text</type>     <!-- How do I state this property is a file? -->
            </property>
        </properties>
    </type>
</types>
```

Comment: Asked and answered in the Alfresco forums: http://forums.alfresco.com/comment/148318#comment-148318

Comment: Hey @vegemite4me, I know it's 2019 now, but did you find a solution to this?
I managed to create a custom type using <type>d:content</type>, but how would I upload a file into that property via REST API?

I've tried encoding a PDF in base64 and passing that string as the property's value, but when I retrieve the node it says that the content is 0 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bad idea doing that. Amongst other things, the system will not give you decent ootb support to search or access the values. Make sure to check associations as an alternative.

That said, if you still want to do that, use a property of type `d:content`. Have a look at http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide for further details.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the audio file and PDF files should be added as content, and only after that is a Whitepaper created, which references the two items, defined as associations? (I'm new to Alfresco ... in case it isn't obvious.)

Comment: Yes. Order of the operations does not have to matter though - depends on whether you make the assocation 1:1 (mandatory) or not.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is to create association i would advice you to do  this:

```
<associations>
            <association name="sc:pdfFiles">
               <source>
                  <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                  <many>true</many>
               </source>
               <target>
                  <class>cm:content</class>
                  <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                  <many>true</many>
               </target>
            </association>
         </associations>
```

Or if this does not fix your problem you can set that property to be of type  `<type>d:content</type>.`

Like so:
        
            d:content

If you are not familiar with custom models you can read more here
http://alfrescoblog.com/2014/05/19/alfresco-tutorial-custom-content-types/

Hope it helps.